# parse xml with batch file

Tags: xml, string, batch-file, extract

Trying to extract two strings of information from a xml file. In the example linkage.xml file, I'd like the batch file to run and create a directory Smith-John-yyyy-mm-dd. So far I am able to generate a folder with the date in the format I want (yyyy-mm-dd), but I am unable to extract "Smith" and "John" as variables. Help would be greatly appreciated.

### linkage.xml

```
<LinkageParameter> 
   <Patient LastName="Smith" FirstName="John" ChartNumber="123">
      <Birthday>18/12/1972</Birthday>
      <Address>123 Main St, Salem, OR</Address>
      <ZipCode>97302</ZipCode>
      <Phone>(503)363-5432</Phone>
      <Mobile>(503)215-3215</Mobile>
      <SocialID>123456789</SocialID>
      <Gender>Male</Gender> 
   </Patient>
</LinkageParameter>
```

---

### My folder.bat file

```
@echo off
for /f %%i in ('xml.exe sel -t -v "//LastName" CP.xml') do set var=%%i
for /f %%i in ('xml.exe sel -t -v "//LastName" CP.xml') do set var=%%j

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

:: Extract date fields - language dependent
for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=/-. " %%i in ('date /t') do (
        set v1=%%i& set v2=%%j& set v3=%%k
        if "%%i:~0,1%%" gtr "9" (set v1=%%j& set v2=%%k& set v3=%%l)

        for /f "skip=1 tokens=2-4 delims=(-)" %%m in ('echo.^|date') do (
            set %%m=!v1!& set %%n=!v2!& set %%o=!v3!
    )
)

:: Final set for language independency (English and Portuguese - maybe works for Spanish and French)
set year=%yy%%aa%
set month=%mm%
set day=%dd%

md \\192.168.0.34\OpenDentImages\PatientImages\CT\%i%-%j%-%year%-%month%-%day%
```

Comment: Not sure where you got `xml.exe` from but Windows has native capability to read XML files with Vbscript and Jscript.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `xml.exe`, and as long as the xml files are similar to that posted, you could try:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "Pre="
For /F Tokens^=2^,4Delims^=^" %%A In ('Find "<Patient"^<"linkage.xml"'
) Do Set Pre=%%A-%%B
If Not Defined Pre GoTo :EOF
```

The variable `%Pre%` should in the case you've provided read `Smith-John`

Answer (score 0):

try with [xpath.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/xpath0.1.bat) (no need to install external binaries):

```
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in ('xpath.bat linkage.xml "//Patient/@LastName"') do set "last_name=%%~a"

for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in ('xpath.bat linkage.xml "//Patient/@FirstName"') do set "first_name=%%~a"

echo %first_name%    %last_name%
```